# MySQL - Can 'INSERT INTO - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' cause data loss

Tags: php, mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have a caching script that requests a bunch of data from a SOAP API using PHP (Cron job every 5 minutes). This script requests and stores a customer `id` and `name`.

The table that the API information is stored in has 3 columns:

```
'id' = int, Primary_key
'name' = varchar(255)
'paying' = bool
```

There is around 10 (in 80) customers with the bool `paying` set to true. However, every once in a while the all customer's `paying` columns revert to `0`.

So... Can the following query cause the `paying` column to change under any circumstances?

```
INSERT INTO customer(`id`, `name`) VALUES ('$escapedId','$escapedName') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name`='$escapedName'
```

Comment: Do you have a unique index on the customer table in your database? or any other index?

Comment: @kejsu The `id` column is the primary key, the columns `id` and `name` are provided by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query couldn't change the 'paying' field state.

Therefore, most likely the reason is some other code that is either setting the value to 0, or just deleting all records.